# Perform a click on a web app with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape or crawl this web app (https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/)
I not sure if its because its a web app or some anti scraper measures but nothing is happening when I attempt to click the login button.

the button is clicked but doesn't show anything.

*Code*

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]').click()
```

you simply didn't add the quotes to the url

Comment: Sorry that was just an issue pasting the script here, I worded it poorly the page opens correctly but the click doesn't carry out it just sits on the page.

Comment: actually the script is working and performs the click but web app doesn't accept it, strange